# How to get AWS Amplify Admin Queries API to be restricted to multiple user pool groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Let's say we have this use case where we have let's say 3 user pool groups: Super Admin, Regular Admin and User.
We want the first 2 groups to be able to create users:

1. Super Admins to create Regular Admins and Users.
2. Regular Admins should only be able to create Users.

Does Amplify CLI or Console support this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

There is [a request](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/6716) for this feature, go give it a thumbs up so it gets Amplify team's attention.

As a workaround, you can do this by hacking the generated CloudFormation template and Lambda code. It's simpler than it sounds.

1. Give any group admin access [using Amplify cli](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/auth/admin).
2. Update the generated CloudFormation template in `amplify/backend/function/AdminQueries<some id>/AdminQueries<another id>.json`, find `"GROUP": "<group name>",` in the environment variable section, add as many groups as you want here, use some kind of delimiters so you can parse it in the Lambda function.
3. Update `amplify/backend/function/AdminQueries<some id>/src/app.js`, find [this line](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/blob/97f16c4c433405663cc0c4815296d34892a89c71/packages/amplify-category-auth/resources/adminAuth/admin-auth-app.js#L59), it checks if the user is in the group defined in CloudFormation. Here you can parse the group list you set in the above step and check multiple groups.

You need to reapply the workaround every time you run `amplify update auth`. Also, the Lambda function code template may change in future versions.

Comment: This was very helpful for me. For reference, these are the lines of code that I updated.
LINE 48 `const allowedGroups = process.env.GROUP.split(',');`
LINE 65 `if (!(allowedGroups && allowedGroups.some((ag) => groups.includes(ag))))`